# How to initialize arbitrary precision?

Tags: arbitrary-precision, precision-and-accuracy

How do I calculate $$\frac{1}{{\frac{1}{7 \times 10^7}- \frac{8\times10^{17}\times 3.1\times 10^7}{6.7 \times 10^{-11}\times \left(1.9 \times 10^{27}\right)^2} }}\tag{1}$$

To [arbitrary precision](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/numbers/arbitrary-precision/)?

I put it into Wolfram Alpha and it simply returns the value $7\times 10^7$

*Remark: I am new here and this is my first question since this stack exchange site is called 'Mathematica and Wolfram Language' I assumed questions about [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%2F%287*10%5E7%29-%20%288*10%5E%7B17%7D*3.1*10%5E7%29%2F%286.7*10%5E%7B-11%7D*%281.9*10%5E%7B27%7D%29%5E2%29%29) were allowed.
If it turns out that this stack exchange site is only for Mathematica then I have that downloaded also, but I am a complete beginner so I'm not sure which command gives arbitrary precision.*

Could someone please explain how to get a precise value of $(1)$ with Mathematica?

Comment: It would be nice if you could give the input expression as type into WA so others can just copy it and don't have to translate it from the latex input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1/(1/(7*10^7) - (8*10^17*31*10^6)/(67*10^-12*(19*10^26)^2))
(*    2116362500000000000000/30233749999783    *)

% // N
(*    7.*10^7    *)

N[2116362500000000000000/30233749999783, 100]
(*    7.000000000050241865465279777890799709324920115332153889776394836700094354142768279649364723750243094*10^7    *)
```